# JPA : Auto create stored procedures

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Just a design question and not looking for any code.

Is it possible to auto create stored procedures in mysql through JPA? Just like how we can configure tables to be automatically created on starting the application?

I couldn't find any sources in the internet for this.

If yes, can you please provide documentation for it?

Comment: Execute `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` unconditionally while the application starts simply..

Comment: That can be done, but this about stored procedures. Is there anyway to achieve similar functionality where the procedure is automatically created  while starting the JPA application?

Comment: Create this procedure once - as a step of your application installation / database creation process. Then simply call it on the application start.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL 8.0, you can do the same thing as you do for tables. MySQL 8.0 added the `IF NOT EXISTS` optional clause to the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement. In MySQL 5.x, that statement did not support the `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax.

Compare the different syntax in the reference documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

The bug report about the missing `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax shows that it was requested in 2005 and implemented in version 8.0.29: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15287

However, I wouldn't design an application to create tables or procedures *every* time it starts. You can create them yourself, once, and then when your application starts and connects to the database, they will be there. If you forget to create the tables or procedures, the application will get errors when it tries to reference them in queries, but you'll know this quickly and correct the situation. Again, you only need to do this once.

Comment: Usually when you create a procedure, you want to make sure it the one you wish to create and not an old version of it. Therefore it is safer to execute `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS` before creating a procedure. And yes, you create/re-create the procedures only when you need to.

Comment: MySQL really needs a `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` statement, so that kind of upgrade can be done atomically. That's at least one thing that MariaDB added that is a good idea.